# How to get Big Sur to respect local PiHole DNS configuration

Tags: macos, dns, pihole

I have a service running on a static IP within my LAN and PiHole specifies a domain name for that IP address.  For example, my.server.com === 192.168.1.10.  Prior to Big Sur, this worked fine.  Now, it keeps reverting to whatever global DNS records specify instead of the address provided by PiHole.  If I clear the DNS cache with `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` the name will resolve to the desired IP address for a very short time (less than a minute or two) and then revert to the global records.  Short of using /etc/hosts how can I get Big Sur to respect PiHole's DNS?

Comment: I don't think this is strictly, directly a Big Sur effect.  I think what may be happening is systems on our LAN running Big Sur are causing a LOT more traffic now.  Lot's a connections to Apple's servers, constantly.  This has overwhelmed the machine running PiHole, causing sluggish responses.  Our router fails over to a non-pihole DNS if PiHole cannot resolve quickly.  If I remove the failover DNS, the static IP override will stick.  So, I need to determine why Big Sur is creating so much more traffic or upgrade our PiHole.

Comment: And it just lost the static IP again, despite removing the failover DNS from the router.  It took quite a while longer this time.  So, from the router perspective and from PiHole, my.server.com === 192.168.1.10 and there is no alternative IP; however, Big Sur seemingly has it "in mind" that it should trust a more authoritative upstream DNS instead of local configuration.  Interestingly, ad blocking in general works. It's just this one custom override failing.

Comment: Last update.  I'm going to change the upstream records or use /etc/hosts. `brctl log -w --shorten` and other network tools hint that everything you do on macOS is now chattering with Apple servers.  You open an app, chatter, you merely start to save a file even if you cancel, chatter.  Search your local machine, chatter, every keypress ping ping ping.  Whether or not macOS has been doing this all along, I dunno, but it's so much now that it's having a significant effect on my PiHole service, and that seemingly causes Big Sur to use another means of resolving domain names.

Comment: Did you see this also with Catalina? Also, are any of the Apple servers in piholes blacklist?